# What happens to items carried by familiars?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

What happens to items carried by familiars?

The *Find Familiar* spell says that as an action you can temporarily dismiss your familiar, and then on a second action make it reappear within 30 feet of you.

If my familiar had been carrying something, say a potion of healing, what happens to the potion when the familiar is dismissed and reappeared?